# Group associative row data based on shared column value

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, grouping, associative-array, array-merge

I have a multidimensional array like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [division] => Mymensingh
            [A] => 1
        )    
    [1] => Array
        (
            [division] => Dhaka
            [A] => 5
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [division] => Mymensingh
            [B] => 2
            [C] => 5
        )
)
```

I need to find the rows with matching `division` values and merge them in one array.

From this array, I want the output as:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [division] => Mymensingh
                [A] => 1
                [B] => 2
                [C] => 5
            )    
        [1] => Array
            (
                [division] => Dhaka
                [A] => 5
            )
    )
```

Keys in the subarrays can be different and the subarrays may have a differing number of elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's relatively simple to just iterate through the array and continuously merge the entries separated by "division":

```
function mergeByDiscriminator($input, $discriminator = 'division') {
    $result = [];

    foreach ($input as $array) {
        $key = $array[$discriminator];
        $result[$key] = array_merge(
            array_key_exists($key, $result) ? $result[$key] : [],
            $array
        );
    }

    return array_values($result);
}

$result = mergeByDiscriminator($input); // $input is your array
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I can think of is as below. Of course there might be other feasable solutions, but I am giving one from my end.

```
$array = array(
   '0' => array (
       'division' => 'Mymensingh',
       'A' => 1
   ),
   '1' => array (
       'division' => 'Dhaka',
       'A' => 5
   ),
   '2' => array (
       'division' => 'Mymensingh',
       'B' => 2,
       'C' => 5
   ),
);

$result = array();
foreach ($array as $arr) {
    if (!is_array($result[$arr['division']])) $result[$arr['division']] = array();

    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        $result[$arr['division']][$key] = $value;
    }
}

echo "<pre>"; print_r($result);
```

The above code is giving you the desired output. Please give it a try.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This task is concisely completed with zero iterated function calls thanks to the null coalescing operator and the union operator.

Merge each iterated row with the pre-existing data in that keyed-group.  If the keyed-group has not yet been encountered merge the row with an empty array.

The union operator is suitable/reliable in this case because it is writing one associative array into another associative array.

Language Construct Iteration: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/WjHvc))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $result[$row['division']] = ($result[$row['division']] ?? []) + $row;
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

Functional Iteration: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/vNFCD))

```
var_export(
    array_values(
        array_reduce(
            $array,
            function($result, $row) {
                $result[$row['division']] = ($result[$row['division']] ?? []) + $row;
                return $result;
            },
            []
        )
    )
);
```